Doubts on the Einstein equations
I have some doubts about the Einstein Equation and in some basics of field theory.
Einstein's equations arise from the principle of least action, which is applied to the Einstein-Hilbert action plus a term
$ _

​$
, associated with a matter field (like a fluid, dust, etc.).
These equations are essentially the equations of motion for the metric, relating curvature (and hence the metric) to energy and momentum. However, to describe a complete theory, it's not enough to vary the action with respect to the metric alone; it must also be varied with respect to the matter field
$$, yielding a system of differential equations.
For example, if I want to study electromagnetism in a curved spacetime, I write the action as the Maxwell action (with the electromagnetic field tensor) plus the Einstein-Hilbert action (which is the kinetic term of the metric). I then extremize the action first with respect to the vector potential (resulting in the Maxwell equations in curved spacetime, which describe the motion of the electromagnetic field) and second with respect to the metric (which gives Einstein's equations with the energy-momentum tensor in a specific form for the electromagnetic field).
Is my reasoning correct? I tried to think as I would if I was dealing with two independent fields in a classical (Euclidean) field theory problem.

Yes. Your reasoning is correct.

Thank you for the answer!

About the phrase: 'Einstein's equations arise from the principle of least action'. It seems to me: the Einstein-Hilbert action arises from the Einstein Field equations. I mean that in the following sense: the process of arriving at the Einstein-Hilbert action is a process of reverse engineering; what form does an action need to have such that differentiation of that action with respect to variation recovers Einstein Field equations? In and of itself the stationary action concept does not provide the means to arrive at the Einstein Field equations.

@Cleonis - The modern point of view is that the action comes first. Einstein's equations then follow from the principle of least action. Of course, historically, the equations were written down before the action.
